# Updating a Reference as a Class Member

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding references.

In the code below, I'd like to initialize A to have a state, but at some time in the future, when I call init (registering a B object to A), I'd like stateB variable to show the value of the B state.

I can do this by making stateB a pointer, then initializing some memory in A's constructor and setting it to the default, then moving this pointer and deleting the memory when calling init.

Can I do this without stateB being a pointer by changing the reference of stateB to be b->state?

```
Class A {
public:
  int stateB = 0;
  B *b = nullptr;
  void init(B *b) {
     &state = &b->state;
  }
}

class B {
public:
  int state = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this line is invalid:

```
&state = &b->state;
```

You cannot assign to the address of `state`. All you can do is `state = b->state`, but that will not meet all your required semantics. That leaves you with a couple options. You can make `stateB` a pointer:

```
class A {
    int* stateB;

public:
    void init(B* b) {
        stateB = &b->state;
    }
};
```

But you **cannot** make `stateB` a reference. References must be initialized and can never be reassigned. So if you want your `A` to be reinitialized to multiple different `B`s, then you'll have to stick with a pointer. However, if you want to effectively bind `A` to a single `B`, then a reference is fine:

```
class A {
    int& stateB;
public:
    A(B& b) : stateB(b.state) { } // must be initialized
                                  // in the ctor
                                  // this A can only ever point to this
                                  // specific B
{ };
```

Note that *both* of these solutions can suffer from a dangling pointer/reference if the `B` goes out of scope while you still have the `A` that is referring to its state. One solution to that problem would be to simply use `shared_ptr`:

```
class A {
    std::shared_ptr<int> stateB;

public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
    : stateB(b, &b->state)  // "aliasing" constructor
    { }
};
```

That makes sure that the `B` will stay alive at least as long as the `A`.